# Ayuda con condicion en un codigo

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código .

```
package p01;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P01 {
private String estudiante;
private String nombre; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] estudiante = {"Nahum Deavila","Genesis Machado","Juan Giraldo","Jose Diana","Cindy Salazar"};
     double[] definitiva = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
     int i;

       for (i = 0; i < definitiva.length; i++) {
                 System.out.print("Estudiante " + estudiante[i] + " Definitiva : " + definitiva[i] + "\n");
   }
  }
}
```

`

como puedo hacer para que en vez de imprimir el nombre y la definitiva pueda poner una condición de que si es mayor a 3.0 aprobó la asignatura. no se como acomodarlo en el código. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar un `if` donde la **definitiva** sea mayor a 3:

```
for (i = 0; i < definitiva.length; i++) {
    if(definitiva[i] > 3.0){
        System.out.print("Aprobado\n");
    }else {
        System.out.print("Estudiante " + estudiante[i] + " Definitiva : " + definitiva[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```